# How many wires can I put in this recessed light junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m installing some recessed lights (halo) in my basement, and I’m wondering how many conductors I can put in the attached box (pictured), since this light will be at a 3-way junction. I calculated the box volume at 24 in<sup>3</sup>, which should accommodate 12 #14 AWG conductors.

My question is: am I allowed to treat this light box like a traditional junction box for box fill purposes?

Unlike a normal junction box it’s only supported by the light’s framing and is not attached to a stud.

[image]

Comment: I've removed the "additionally" question, because while it's related to the project you're working on, it's really a separate question. I started writing up an answer to it, but it would be incomplete because I don't know the answer to the first part of the question. _Please_ feel free to ask a second question about where you can locate it, but be sure to _first_ search for the answer here, because I'm 99.999% sure that you'll realize the answer without having to ask it.

Comment: That said, I'd imagine you can use it as a "regular" j-box since it's attached to a bracket which is, in turn, attached to a stud/joist. Go search your local big-box store's electrical aisle and you'll see plenty of boxen with pre-attached brackets for hanging them on a piece of wood. None of those expect any further attachment _of the box itself_ to a stud...

Comment: Also keep in mind that all boxes must remain *accessible*. In a ceiling that becomes a big problem for a box that is "just a box" because most people don't like blank/filler plates in the ceiling. (Exception: with a drop-ceiling there is no accessibility issue - just remove a tile.) So a junction box that is by design integral to the light fixture works but a nearly identical box 6" away does not.

Comment: FYI, you can save yourself some hassle and expense by bringing multiple cables in through a single clamp. They'll accept at least two and probably three.

Comment: Usually the box fill is printed (engraved) right on those (either the box or its cover), and may be different from "calculated" box fill (and manufacturers instructions rule in that case.)